# Ruby socket break after fork

Tags: ruby, fork, rbvmomi

I am using a Ruby gem to interact with the vmware SDK. I found an interesting issue that I thought I would bring attention to.

I found that if I make a ssl connection to vCenter and it connects successfully, then I fork the processes and try to use the connection, the socket breaks with an error. I am not sure if that is common with sockets and forked processes but I was wondering if someone could shed some light on this. The error I am getting is EOF read_nonblock.

Any insight would be helpful.

thanks,

Comment: are you using the socket from the parent process or the child process? Sockets are based on file descriptors and those may or may not get inherited and/or closed depending on how the fork is performed.

Comment: I created the connection and saved it in a variable. I then forked a child process and called that variable in the child.